# Split a string on each "X"

Tags: python, regex, awk, sed, split

I'm trying to `split` a `string` on each `Cell\s\d+` without success.
My attempt was:

```
result = re.split(r"Cell\s\d+ - Address: .*?Cell\s\d+", subject, 0, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

But it skips every 1 record, which makes sense, because I'm including part of the next match on the regex. 
I've also tried positive/negative lookahead and lookbehind without luck.
Please note that records end differently.

How do I split the string below?

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
Cell 01 - Address: 00:24:01:B6:4F:E1
Channel:3
Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm
Encryption key:on
ESSID:"DLink-XXXXXX"
Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
Mode:Master
Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
Extra: Last beacon: 20ms ago
IE: Unknown: 000C444C696E6B2D423634464531
IE: Unknown: 010882848B0C12961824
IE: Unknown: 030103
IE: WPA Version 1
Group Cipher : TKIP
Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
IE: Unknown: 2A0100
IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101050003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
IE: Unknown: DD0A00037F04010000000000
Cell 02 - Address: 06:24:01:B6:4F:E1
Channel:3
Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
Quality=70/70  Signal level=-39 dBm
Encryption key:on
ESSID:"WIFI_1"
Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
Mode:Master
Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
Extra: Last beacon: 20ms ago
IE: Unknown: 00015F
IE: Unknown: 010882848B0C12961824
IE: Unknown: 030103
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
Group Cipher : TKIP
Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
IE: Unknown: 2A0100
IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101050003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
IE: Unknown: DD0A00037F04010000000000
Cell 03 - Address: BC:4D:FB:4F:C3:B8
Channel:7
Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm
Encryption key:on
ESSID:"WIFI_2"
Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
Mode:Master
Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
Extra: Last beacon: 20ms ago
IE: Unknown: 00083F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F
IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
IE: Unknown: 030107
IE: Unknown: 32048C98B060
IE: Unknown: DD270050F204104A0001101044000102104700102880288028801880A880BC4DFB4FC3B8103C000101
IE: Unknown: 050402030080
IE: Unknown: 2A0100
IE: Unknown: 2D1A8C0116FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
IE: Unknown: 3D1607000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
IE: Unknown: 7F0101
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
Group Cipher : CCMP
Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
IE: Unknown: 0B0506001B127A
IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000
Cell 04 - Address: BC:4D:FB:4F:C3:B9
Channel:7
Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
Quality=68/70  Signal level=-42 dBm
Encryption key:off
ESSID:"NOS_WIFI_Fon"
Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
Mode:Master
Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
Extra: Last beacon: 20ms ago
IE: Unknown: 000C4E4F535F574946495F466F6E
IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
IE: Unknown: 030107
IE: Unknown: 32048C98B060
IE: Unknown: 050401030000
IE: Unknown: 2A0100
IE: Unknown: 2D1A8C0116FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
IE: Unknown: 3D1607000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
IE: Unknown: 7F0101
IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
IE: Unknown: 0B0506001B127A
IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000
```

Comment: It is usually done like `r"Cell\s\d+ - Address: .*?(?=Cell\s\d+|\Z)"`. You may even add `\n` before `Cell` in the lookahead to make it safer (if the `Cell` is at the beginning of a line).

Comment: Why is this tagged `awk` and `sed`?  Do you want a solution using those?

Comment: @chrisz solutions using `awk` or `sed` were also welcome, but @Wiktor nailed it already. Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative approach, you could use Python's `groupby()` function to spot the blocks as follows:

```
from itertools import groupby

subject = """ --- all the text --- """    # read in, or add text here
lines = iter(subject.splitlines())
data = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(lines, lambda x: x.startswith('Cell '))][1:]
cells = [l1 + l2 for l1, l2 in zip(*[iter(data)] * 2)]

for cell in cells:
    print cell
```

So if `subject` contains all the text from a file, you would get four cells each containing a list of lines for each:

```
['Cell 01 - Address: 00:24:01:B6:4F:E1', 'Channel:3', 'Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)', 'Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm', 'Encryption key:on', 'ESSID:"DLink-XXXXXX"', 'Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s', '11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s', 'Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s', 'Mode:Master', 'Extra:tsf=0000000000000000', 'Extra: Last beacon: 20ms ago', 'IE: Unknown: 000C444C696E6B2D423634464531', 'IE: Unknown: 010882848B0C12961824', 'IE: Unknown: 030103', 'IE: WPA Version 1', 'Group Cipher : TKIP', 'Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP', 'Authentication Suites (1) : PSK', 'IE: Unknown: 2A0100', 'IE: Unknown: 32043048606C', 'IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101050003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00', 'IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F', 'IE: Unknown: DD0A00037F04010000000000']
['Cell 02 - Address: 06:24:01:B6:4F:E1', 'Channel:3', 'Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)', 'Quality=70/70  Signal level=-39 dBm', 'Encryption key:on', 'ESSID:"WIFI_1"', 'Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s', '11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s', 'Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s', 'Mode:Master', 'Extra:tsf=0000000000000000', 'Extra: Last beacon: 20ms ago', 'IE: Unknown: 00015F', 'IE: Unknown: 010882848B0C12961824', 'IE: Unknown: 030103', 'IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1', 'Group Cipher : TKIP', 'Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP', 'Authentication Suites (1) : PSK', 'IE: Unknown: 2A0100', 'IE: Unknown: 32043048606C', 'IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101050003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00', 'IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F', 'IE: Unknown: DD0A00037F04010000000000']
['Cell 03 - Address: BC:4D:FB:4F:C3:B8', 'Channel:7', 'Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)', 'Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm', 'Encryption key:on', 'ESSID:"WIFI_2"', 'Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s', '18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s', 'Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s', 'Mode:Master', 'Extra:tsf=0000000000000000', 'Extra: Last beacon: 20ms ago', 'IE: Unknown: 00083F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F', 'IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C', 'IE: Unknown: 030107', 'IE: Unknown: 32048C98B060', 'IE: Unknown: DD270050F204104A0001101044000102104700102880288028801880A880BC4DFB4FC3B8103C000101', 'IE: Unknown: 050402030080', 'IE: Unknown: 2A0100', 'IE: Unknown: 2D1A8C0116FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'IE: Unknown: 3D1607000400000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'IE: Unknown: 7F0101', 'IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1', 'Group Cipher : CCMP', 'Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP', 'Authentication Suites (1) : PSK', 'IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00', 'IE: Unknown: 0B0506001B127A', 'IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000']
['Cell 04 - Address: BC:4D:FB:4F:C3:B9', 'Channel:7', 'Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)', 'Quality=68/70  Signal level=-42 dBm', 'Encryption key:off', 'ESSID:"NOS_WIFI_Fon"', 'Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s', '18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s', 'Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s', 'Mode:Master', 'Extra:tsf=0000000000000000', 'Extra: Last beacon: 20ms ago', 'IE: Unknown: 000C4E4F535F574946495F466F6E', 'IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C', 'IE: Unknown: 030107', 'IE: Unknown: 32048C98B060', 'IE: Unknown: 050401030000', 'IE: Unknown: 2A0100', 'IE: Unknown: 2D1A8C0116FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'IE: Unknown: 3D1607000400000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'IE: Unknown: 7F0101', 'IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00', 'IE: Unknown: 0B0506001B127A', 'IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000']
```

Comment: I used Wicktor's comment as a solution, but I'll mark your answer as correct. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262574/split-a-string-on-each-x#comment85528787_49262574